# SWRevealViewController : RearViewController width in iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, swrevealviewcontroller, iphone-6

I am using SWRevealViewController for Sliding Menues in My iPhone App. It seems that, this library uses 260.0f as Rear View width. That's ok for iPhone < 6 . But for iPhone 6 and 6+ , it's appearance is like the following image taken from iPhone 6 plus simulator. I want want same appearance in all iPhones , that means same proportion of rear view width when it is open. Any help about that will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: hello, found an answer to this?

Comment: Nope , Used fixed pixel , I mean I did not use auto-layout for RearViewController to get rid of this problem for this time.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone still has this problem this is the solution.

Open the `SWRevealViewController.m` file and do the following changes to the `_initDefaultProperties` method.

```
- (void)_initDefaultProperties
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    _rearViewRevealWidth = screenRect.size.width - 60.0f; //Default was 260.0f
}
```

As you see, the default value of `_rearViewRevealWidth` is 260.0f, 60.0f lower than the screen width of a regular iPhone (4S, 5) screen.

In this code above we modelling the `rearViewRevealWidth` for every iPhone. First we take the screen size with `screenWidth` and then we do the subtraction.